# React - How to persist checkbox selection when component re-renders but data is same?

Tags: reactjs

I have filters that are opened (and closed) onClick from the Header.
Inside the filters is a button "show all results" that only exists on mobile devices, not on desktop.
On mobile the filters overlap the entire Home screen (like modal).
When user clicks on said button "show all results", filter modal closes and the results are displayed. The problem: when I click again on "open filters" button in header, my past selection (the checked boxes) are gone. It looked like tall got refreshed, but it didn't. I still see the filtered results (that's correct) just that the checkboxes are all unchecked again.
That happens because the FilterItem Component gets re-rendered each time and state (checked property) is again false. I tried to use React.Memo and tried to think of other ways but can't figure out how to do it. Help would be great. Thanks!!

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () =>{
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Main />
    </div>
  )
}

const Header = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(StateContext)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=> dispatch({type: "showFilters"})}>Open filters</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const Main = () => {
  //in this component the logic for fetching and filtering data happens. 
  //fetching --> filters
  const context = React.useContext(StateContext)
  const { state : {showFilters}} = context;
  return (
    <div>
      {
        showFilters && <Filters list={filters} showFilters={showFilters} />
      }    
    </div>
  );
};

const Filters = ({ list, showFilters }) => {
  return (
    <div>
    <ul>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <FilterItem item={item} />
      ))}
    </ul>
    //
    {showFilters && <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: "showFilters"})}>SHow all results</button>} //this has to be here as I also reuse Filters component without that Button (on desktop device vs mobile)
    
    </div>
  );
};

const FilterItem = ({ item }) => {
  const [checked, toggleCheckmark] = React.useState(true)
  const handleCheckBox = () => {
    toggleCheckmark(!checked)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleCheckBox}><CheckBox /></button>
      <li>{item.name}</li>
  </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: You should also pass `checked` to `Checkbox` component. Then you can preserve checked/unchecked state like `checked={checked}`

Comment: I tried that and it also doesn't help. MaybeI misunderstood something - how do you mean  " checked={checked}" ? what would I have inside checkbox - no logic just the checkbox and the checked I pass to checkbox as a prop? then its the same because the component will always re render, setting checked to false, passing it to checkbox

Comment: `<button onClick={handleCheckBox}><CheckBox /></button>` is unclear. Can you also add the code of the `<Checkbox />` component?